# How to activate phaselistener when HTML5 file is called in JSF

Tags: html, jsf-2, unauthorized, phaselistener

I define a `PhaseListener` in JSF project. It is working when `*.xhtml` file is called in browser. But It is not working when `*.html5` file is called in browser. Can do I do `phaseListener` for?

If I can not this check, What can I do instead of `phaseListener`?

Comment: `<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>` If I add *.html to url-pattern, html5 page is not launching. Given error: `HTTP Status 404 - /Tshirt/design.jsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [servlet filter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info) instead.

Here's a basic kickoff example:

```
@WebFilter("*.html5")
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // Perform here some code before processing the request.
        // ...

        chain.doFilter(req, res);

        // Perform here some code after processing the request.
        // ...
    }

}
```